# Adding Values using select2 which are not found in the database?

Tags: select2-rails

I am trying to search a way to add new categories in the present categories for my article using the select2 but as we know it only returns those which are already saved in the database.I want to do something so that those categories which are not there could get created automatically during the Runtime [As figure shows no result found is displayed rather a new category should be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrzFy.png). Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Use the `tags` option, which is described in the official select2 documentation

Comment: Please can u suggest a way to implement this in rails and can i do it if i have a table for the values being stored in a table.

Comment: You might find this gem useful for that https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on